# magento customer group during registration

Tags: customer

i want to assign customer to specific customer group during , registration , how can i do it.

Bascially want to add dropdown , showing list of all available groups from which user can choose

i want to do it via modules or observer which observer should i call to do this pls help

Comment: what about this : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-group-at-registration.html

Answer (score 2):

**Note that this is not tested with group**

What I think you can do with customer attributes is set the attribute to be `used_in_forms`. Then simply add the drop down to the template and Magento will pick up the attribute during the saving of the customer.

You probably want to add the attribute to the following forms.

- checkout_register,
- customer_account_create,

Have a look into `Mage_Customer_AccountController::_getCustomerErrors` to see how the form attribute data is extracted.

Answer (score 1):

This is not available by default settings in magento.  As an alternative to custom coding the solution, check this extension as a highly feasible solution https://amasty.com/customer-attributes.html